# What's the Node.js equivalent of Python's gevent?

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to learn Node.js, both for webapp development but small system srcripts also. With Python, we have this library gevent that implements greenlets and monkey patch Python STD library, so you can write sync code and it'll work as it where async.

Is there something like that but for Node? I've read about async and Fibers but I don't understand if that's a similar approach.

Comment: nodejs is async by design and by default.Therefore no need to patch anything because all libraries are written with async programming in mind.There is no sync library that needs to be patched.You have to write your code async.

Comment: nodejs/javascript is callback by design. Question is about a technique to go from callback-by-design to async-by-design, in python from twisted to gevent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From looking at the first example in gevent's documentation, you're looking for `generators`, which are a bleeding edge feature. You can use them by passing `--harmony_generators` in supporting node versions (currently the unstable 0.11).

Using native generators is not that hard, but I'd recommend the [co module](https://github.com/visionmedia/co/). An example from its readme:

```
co(function *(){
  var a = get('http://google.com');  // an async process
  var b = get('http://yahoo.com');   // an async process
  var c = get('http://cloudup.com'); // an async process
  var res = yield [a, b, c];         // wait until these are done in a
                                     // synchronous style.
  console.log(res);                  // log these objects
})()
```

The other more traditional options would be using promises (multiple libraries exist):

```
doSomeTaskThatReturnsAPromise()
    .then(somethingElse)
    .then(somethingElse)
    .then(function() { console.log("I'm done!") });
```

..or libraries such as [async](https://github.com/caolan/async):

```
async.series([
    doSomeTask,
    somethingElse,
    somethingElse
], function() {
    console.log("I'm done!");
});
```

I have no experience with Fibers, but I believe that it's conceptually similar to Generators.

Comment: Gevent does not use generators - it uses greenlet module which does python stack save/restore to get you coroutine. This is different from python generator - no yield involved.

Comment: This is example of solution using generators: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-announce-list/2007-June/005908.html . Notice the yield keywords everywhere. Gevent fixes that with greenlet.